# Cannot connect PHP to Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have had the hardest time getting PHP to talk to Postgres SQL. Here is my setup:

Ubunu Desktop 13.10
PHP 5.5.3
Postgres 9.1.10
Apache 2.4.6
Netbeans 7.4 with xdebug

Everything is working fine. I am able to enter and retrieve data in the Postgres Database fine from the command line but not in PHP. Here are the lines of code that I am using to connect:

```
$dbConn = new softwareDB('localhost', 'postgres', 'root', 'softwareuitest');
...
  $results = $dbConn.getClients();
    while($client = pg_fetch_result($results)){
        echo '<option value=\"'.$client.'\">'.$client.'</option>';
    }
```

The softwareDB class constructor is as follows:

```
Class softwareDB {

private $conn;

function _construct($host, $user, $password, $dbname) {
    $connectString = 
            'host=' . $host .
            ' port=5432' . 
            ' user=' . $user .
            ' password=' . $password .
            ' dbname' . $dbname;

    $this->conn = pg_connect($connectString);
}
...
public function getClients() {
    global $conn;
    return pg_query($conn,'getClients','SELECT * FROM clients');
}
...
}
```

When running the code nothing happens... I see nothing in the Apache log file, nothing in the postgres log, nothing from the debugger, and only HTML (without query data) in the output.

I cannot post images yet but here are the details about Postgres from phpInfo():

**PDO**
PDO Drivers | pgsql

**pdo_pgsql**
version 9.1.9
module 1.0.2
revision $id$

**pgsql**
PostgreSQL(libpq) | PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu1) 4.8.1, 64-bit
allow_persistent is on

Comment: Gah, why would you use `global $conn`? Just use `$this->conn`. Also, PHP uses the arrow operator (`->`) to reference class instance methods, not the dot so it should be `$dbConn->getClients()`

Comment: A little new to PHP here. I fully agree. Will be changed immediately!

Comment: Also, where's your error checking for connection failures?

Comment: I have these lines right below the call to softwareDB:
`if(!$dbConn){
    die(pg_last_error());
}`

Comment: Another thing, `pg_query` only takes 2 arguments (not 3) and `pg_fetch_result` takes 2 or 3 (certainly not 1). I suggest you read the manual pages for the functions you're using

Answer (score 1):

You have two main issues. The first is a typo; PHP class instance methods are called via the arrow operator. It should be...

```
$results = $dbConn->getClients();
```

The second is your use of `global $conn`. You don't have a variable named `$conn`, global or not. What you do have is a member property `$conn` which you may reference by prefixing it with `$this`, eg

```
public function getClients() {
    return pg_query($this->conn, 'SELECT * FROM clients');
}
```

---

Looking further, I would suggest that if you're going to abstract DB details away in your `softwareDB` class, you might as well do it completely. I'd go with something like this

```
class softwareDB {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $dbname) {
        $this->conn = pg_connect(sprintf('host=%s port=5432 user=%s password=%s dbname=%s',
            $host, $user, $password, $dbname));
        if ($this->conn === false) {
            throw new Exception(pg_last_error());
        }
    }

    public function getClients() {
        $result = pg_query($this->conn, 'SELECT * FROM clients');
        return pg_fetch_all($result);            
    }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with the PostgreSQL Functions so you may need to tweak this but the general idea is that code using your `softwareDB` class doesn't need to know anything about postgres or other DB operations.

Comment: All good suggestions. Many of the error reporting things have been hastily added in an attempt to get any heartbeat from Postgres. I have corrected the error (dot operator and importing the global) but I am getting nothing at all saying that there was a connection to the DB. The debugger just passes on over the function and returns no values for it as if nothing was out of the ordinary.